# Why does Perl 6 try to evaluate an infinite list only in one of two similar situations?

Tags: raku

Suppose I define a lazy, infinite array using a triangular reduction at the REPL, with a single element pasted onto the front:

```
> my @s = 0, |[\+] (1, 2 ... *)
[...]
```

I can print out the first few elements:

```
> @s[^10]
(0 1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45)
```

I'd like to move the zero element inside the reduction like so:

```
> my @s = [\+] (0, |(1, 2 ... *))
```

However, in response to this, the REPL hangs, presumably by trying to evaluate the infinite list.

If I do it in separate steps, it works:

```
> my @s = 0, |(1, 2 ... *)
[...]
> ([\+] @s)[^10]
(0 1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45)
```

Why doesn't the way that doesn't work...work?

Comment: I think this is actually a bug.  For some reason it doesn't consider the `|(1, 2 ... *)` inside the `List` as lazy.  So it starts to reify all elements, until it runs out of memory or you get tired of waiting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:**

It is probably a bug.

---

**Long answer:**

`(1, 2 ... *)` produces a lazy sequence because it is obviously infinite, but somehow that is not making the resulting sequence from being marked as lazy.

Putting a sequence into an array `@s` causes it to be eagerly evaluated unless it is marked as being lazy.

---

**Quick fix:**

Append `lazy` to the front.

```perl6
> my @s = [\+] lazy 0, |(1, 2 ... *)
[...]
> @s[^10]
(0 1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45)
```

Comment: That would be Prepend, neh? (sorry couldn't resist)